# Tomcat8 compression vs. sendfile of Apache Portable Runtime

Tags: apache, tomcat8

Who can explain what sendFile is exactly doing and what pros/cons it has when it comes to compression?

Some (also the manual) seem to advice to disable sendfile on the tomcat connector when using compression.